# Removing unwanted values from a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating a data frame and want to drop entries in it that are not relevant. I'm looking to drop the values that are not numbers.

I have created the data frame using the following code ([credit](https://saturncloud.io/blog/loading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-into-one-dataframe-a-comprehensive-guide/)):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('/pathdirectory/files')
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.csv')]

dfs = []

for csv in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None)
    df = df.T
    df.columns = ['DC energy', 'AC energy', 'Capacity factor', 'Inverter Loss']
    dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
final_df
```

And it returns [this data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REeLl.png). Obviously I want to remove the wording from the data frame but I am struggling with doing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the first columns of the CSVs as index:

```
pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, index_col=0)
```

Alternatively:

```
cols = ['DC energy', 'AC energy', 'Capacity factor', 'Inverter Loss']
    
final_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, index_col=0)
                      for csv in csv_files],
                     axis=1, ignore_index=True).T.set_axis(cols)
```

Note that this assumes that all files have the same order of columns. You could also keep the default name:

```
final_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, index_col=0)
                      for csv in csv_files],
                     axis=1, ignore_index=True).T
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I'm relatively new to Python and sometimes its the simplest things I miss, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Applying this example to your data
    import pandas as pd
        
    # Create a sample DataFrame
    data = {'A': [1, 'text', 2, '123', 3],
                'B': [4, 5, 'abc', 6, '789']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        
    # Convert all values in the DataFrame to numeric, coercing non-numeric values to NaN
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
        
    # Drop rows with NaN values (non-numeric entries)
    df = df.dropna()
        
    # Reset the index if needed
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
        
    # Print the resulting data frame.
        print(df)
```

> #1.We use df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') to convert all
> values in the DataFrame to numeric, coercing non-numeric values to
> NaN.
> 2. We use df.dropna() to drop rows that contain NaN values, which
> correspond to non-numeric entries.
> 3. Optionally, you can reset the
> index using df.reset_index(drop=True) if you want the index to be
> continuous without any gaps.
> 4. After running this code, df will
> contain only the rows with numeric values, and non-numeric entries
> will be dropped.

Comment: Please, format your answer properly.